# Why timezone in angular doesn't work as expected in the following case

Tags: angularjs

I'm using legacy AngularJS 1.3

I have the following code

```
{{ (1475586000*1000) | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' : 'Australia/Lord_Howe'}}
```

In UTC, `1475586000` is `04 Oct 2016 13:00:00 GMT`

---

Since `Australia/Lord_Howe` is +11, I expect `2016-10-05` should be printed.

However, `2016-10-04` is printed. May I know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs for AngularJS v1.3.19 ...

> Timezone to be used for formatting. Right now, only 'UTC' is
>   supported. If not specified, the timezone of the browser will be used.

Looking at the documentation for the latest 1.5 release ...

> Timezone to be used for formatting. It understands UTC/GMT and the
>   continental US time zone abbreviations, but for general use, use a
>   time zone offset, for example, '+0430' (4 hours, 30 minutes east of
>   the Greenwich meridian) If not specified, the timezone of the browser
>   will be used.

... which gives the clue that you can get closer to what you want by using an offset, although that presumably gives daylight savings issues so it is not the same thing:

```
{{ (1475586000*1000) | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' : '+11:00'}}
```